# kick/ban people in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I have created a discord.py bot, and I am adding a functionality to the bot so it can ban and kick people. There is a problem, however. Whenever I enter !!kick @user_account OR !!ban @user_account, it does nothing. I have also tried changing the work "ctx" to "message", but the same thing happens. Help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

```
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await member.kick(reason=reason)

@client.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
  await member.ban(reason=reason)
```

Comment: The Discord.py library produces plenty of logging. See the output so you know what goes wrong

Comment: Is there any stderr output, or it just doesn't perform the task? What I can think of here is the kick_member and ban_member permissions, but that should raise Forbidden.

Comment: so, it doesn't output any errors. thanks for the info

Comment: I say on internet the very easily by tapping "kick and ban discord.py". Before asking a question here, please read the documentation and search on internet for answers

Comment: Hello. Yes, thats just what I did. There was a problem, I couldn't find anything. Maybe I should have searched more, but I just thought, why not present the question here, so someone could helpfully assist me. :)

Answer (score 0):

here is ban kick unban code discord py and the error under the command is so people with no perms cant do them

> #--- kick command --- @client.command() @commands.guild_only() @commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True) async def kick(ctx, user:
> discord.Member, *, reason=None):   await user.kick(reason=reason)
> await ctx.send(f"{user} Has been kicked!")
>
> @kick.error async def kick(ctx, error):    if isinstance(error,
> commands.MissingPermissions):
> await ctx.send("You dont have premissions to run this command")
>
> #--- ban command --- @client.command() @commands.guild_only() @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True) async def ban(ctx, user:
> discord.Member, *, reason=None):
> await user.ban(reason=reason)
> await ctx.send(f"{user} Has been banned!")
>
> @ban.error async def ban(ctx, error):    if isinstance(error,
> commands.MissingPermissions):
> await ctx.send("You dont have premissions to run this command")
>
> #--- unban command --- @client.command() @commands.guild_only() @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True) async def unban(ctx, id:
> int):
> user_id = await client.fetch_user(id)
> await ctx.guild.unban(user_id)
> await ctx.send(f"{user_id} Has been unbanned!")
>
> @unban.error async def ban(ctx, error):    if isinstance(error,
> commands.MissingPermissions):
> await ctx.send("You dont have premissions to run this command")

Answer (score 0):

I have my own bot and it appears to work on my end. Since you say no error is printed, you'll have to print out what the error is by doing something like the following:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandError): # if a command fails
            print(error) # print the error
```

OR, if you want to do it for each individual command:

```
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandError): # if a command fails
            print(error) # print the error

@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandError): # if a command fails
            print(error) # print the error
```

Once you find out the error, try solving it.